# How can I see the values of a ManyToMany field based on a Foreign key value in Django Admin Panel?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I am making a **Django** app for **multiple choice question-answer** exam. I have created a **Subject, Question and Exam model** as below.

```
    class Subject(models.Model):
        subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
        subject_code = models.IntegerField(blank=False)

    class Question(models.Model):
        subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        question_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)

    class Exam(models.Model):
        subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
        date_of_exam = models.DateField(blank=False)
        users = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser)
```

Here in Question I am connecting subject by Foreign Key relation. In Exam I have subject as Foreign key and questions as ManyToMany relation from Question model.

I want to create exam from admin panel. I want that when I select a subject only the questions of that subject should be displayed in the manytomany field to select from (As questions have foreign key of subject I think it should be possible).

(I want to do this from admin panel only and not from a template.)

How can I achieve this? Any suggetion is very much appreciated.

*Thanks in advance for the suggestions*!!  **:)**

Answer (score 0):

The solution i can think of would require you to attempt to submit and then the many2many field would then be populated with the questions that are linked to the selected subject if it was selected.

##### in your forms.py

```py
class ExamAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        subject = cleaned_data.get("subject")

        if subject:
            # Adjust the queryset of field2 based on the value of field1
            self.fields["questions"].queryset = Question.objects.filter(subject=subject)

        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = Exam
        fields = "__all__"
```

##### in your admin.py file

```py
...

@admin.register(Exam)
class ExamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ExamAdminForm
```